# Sharing a proof on ResearchGate? Inappropriate?

Tags: publications, social-media

Is it inappropriate to share a proof of a manuscript online, such as ResearchGate? The manuscript is part of a large special session in a journal that currently has no publication date yet..

Comment: This likely depends on the publisher's policies, especially if you have transferred copyright to them.  Some publishers may allow it and others don't.  The publisher should have their copyright policy and agreement posted, or have sent you a copy when the paper was accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at your copyright agreement - many will differentiate between the preprint, postprint, and the final published version.

Default language in copyright agreement tends to be most restrictive with the final published version and least restrictive with the preprint.

You can always contact the publisher and specifically ask for permission. I've done this in the past and even gotten special permission to post the final published version (they asked I prominently add the publication and DOI to the 1st page).

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth: [this link](https://www.acm.org/publications/policies/simultaneous-submissions), from the website of ACM (a large publisher in computer science), says that "An author posting a paper on commercial piracy sites (such as ResearchGate) knowing they have assigned copyright to the publisher is in violation of the copyright agreement the author entered into with their publisher as it is illegal sharing of the published work".

Comment: That's why I usually edit and negotiate the copyright agreement to include rights for authors to post preprint to "institutional repositories, personal websites and repositories, and *academic social media sites*."